# Link cannot be clicked on top of slider

Tags: html, css

I have a slider created from html and css.I added a text link within the html coding along with the css,but the problem when I position it above the slider image,it cannot be clicked.I tried using z-index attribute but in vain.

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3rvzd/

Html:

```
<!-- radio buttons and labels -->
<input id="select-img-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-1" checked/>
<label for="select-img-1" class="cr-label-img-1">1</label>

<input id="select-img-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-2" />
<label for="select-img-2" class="cr-label-img-2">2</label>

<input id="select-img-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-3" />
<label for="select-img-3" class="cr-label-img-3">3</label>

<input id="select-img-4" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-4" />
<label for="select-img-4" class="cr-label-img-4">4</label>

<div class="clr"></div> 

<!-- panels -->
<div class="cr-bgimg">
    <div>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- titles -->
<div class="cr-titles">
    <h3> 
       <span>Surface Pro</span>
        <span>What you've been dreaming of</span>
<a class="sliderlink" href="http://www.google.com">$300</a> 
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Adventure</span>
        <span>Where the fun begins</span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Nature</span>
        <span>Unforgettable eperiences</span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Serenity</span>
        <span>When silence touches nature</span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your elements is hovering this `anchor`...

Delete the following setting:

```
.cr-titles h3 {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: I see it works on jsfiddle.I have deleted it in my css.I am waiting to see it take effect.Its because I have a problem of cache.

Comment: Just clean your browser's cache. Try `ctrl+F5` for start

Comment: I did it,but it still did not take the new settings.I am using cloudflare,maybe thats why it takes time.But when I remove the z-index:10000 on the inspect element of my browser,the link works,but  the main title disappears...

Comment: It doesn't happen in your fiddle

Comment: I dont understand why.

Comment: THe css took effect on my website.And thats exactly what happened.The heading Surface Pro disappeared.

Comment: You didn't give me any link showing the actual problem, how can I help you?

Comment: Sorry.The link is www.dailycrazydeals.com.

Comment: Give this element you want to bring to front `z-index: 1000` or something

Comment: i tried that,but it didnt work.When I remove the z-index for .cr-titles h3, the header disappears,but the link works.And when I leave the z-index and put a greater z-index for my link(class:sliderlink), the header appears,but the link no longer works

Comment: @user2768474 Add this style `.cr-titles h3:first-child {
    z-index: 1000;
}`

Comment: can i add a timer to make the slides move by themselves after a certain time?

Comment: Google `jQuery slider or slideshow`. Anyway, you're supposed to **accept** answers that helped you.

Comment: ok thanks,i will accept the answer.I am a bit new to stackoverflow,thats why i didnt know.